# JavaFX - Java.lang.RuntimeException A bound value cannot be set

Tags: javafx, binding

I done a Small Java FX project and I used multiplication bindings for one of my columns so that it updates on the fly. The problem that I am having is that I cannot open an XML file with the bindings as it giving me the above error in the title. Here is the Code for my Items

```
public class Items {

    private final StringProperty name;
    private final IntegerProperty quantity;
    private final DoubleProperty price;
    private final DoubleProperty total;

      public Items() {
          this(null,0,0); 
          }


    public Items(String name, int quantity, double price) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.quantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty(quantity);
        this.price = new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);
        this.total = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        NumberBinding multiplication = Bindings.multiply(
        this.priceDoubleProperty(), this.quantityIntegerProperty());
        this.totalProperty().bind(multiplication);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty NameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity.get();
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity.set(quantity);
    }

    public IntegerProperty quantityIntegerProperty() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price.get();
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    public DoubleProperty priceDoubleProperty() {
        return price;
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return total.get();
    }

    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total.set(total);

    }

    public DoubleProperty totalProperty() {
        return total;
    }

}
```

And here is the MainApp Code

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;
    public static ObservableList<Items> itemData = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList();

    public MainApp() {
        // Add some sample data
        itemData.add(new Items("Hans", 0, 0));
        itemData.add(new Items("Ruth", 0, 0));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data as an observable list of Persons.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public ObservableList<Items> getItemData() {
        return itemData;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Shopping Basket");
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(400);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(600);
        primaryStage.setMaxHeight(600);
        primaryStage.setMaxWidth(700);
        this.primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:resources/images/shopping_basket_32.png"));
        initRootLayout();
        showBasketOverview();

    }

    /**
     * Initializes the root layout.
     */
    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class
                    .getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);

            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Try to load last opened person file.
        File file = getItemFilePath();
        if (file != null) {
            loadItemDataFromFile(file);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Opens a dialog to edit details for the specified person. If the user
     * clicks OK, the changes are saved into the provided person object and true
     * is returned.
     * 
     * @param person
     *            the person object to be edited
     * @return true if the user clicked OK, false otherwise.
     */

    /**
     * Shows the person overview inside the root layout.
     */
    public void showBasketOverview() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class
                    .getResource("view/BasketOverview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane BasketOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(BasketOverview);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            BasketOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the main stage.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public boolean showBasketEditDialog(Items item) {
        try {
            // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup dialog.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class
                    .getResource("view/BasketEditDialog.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Create the dialog Stage.
            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("Edit Basket");
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);

            // Set the person into the controller.
            BasketEditDialogController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
            controller.setItems(item);

            // Show the dialog and wait until the user closes it
            dialogStage.showAndWait();

            return controller.isOkClicked();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public File getItemFilePath() {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MainApp.class);
        String filePath = prefs.get("Filepath", null);
        if (filePath != null) {
            return new File(filePath);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setItemFilePath(File file) {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MainApp.class);
        if (file != null) {
            prefs.put("filePath", file.getPath());

            primaryStage.setTitle("Shopping Basket - " + file.getName());
        } else {
            prefs.remove("filePath");
            primaryStage.setTitle("Shopping Basket");
        }
    }

    public void loadItemDataFromFile(File file) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(BasketListWrapper.class);
            Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

            BasketListWrapper wrapper = (BasketListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);

            itemData.clear();
            itemData.addAll(wrapper.getItems());

            setItemFilePath(file);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText(e + "Could not load data"); 
            alert.setContentText("Could not load data from file:\n"
                    + file.getPath());


            alert.showAndWait();

        }
    }

    public void saveItemDataToFile(File file) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(BasketListWrapper.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            BasketListWrapper wrapper = new BasketListWrapper();
            wrapper.setItems(itemData);

            m.marshal(wrapper, file);

            setItemFilePath(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("Could not load data");
            System.out.println(e);
            alert.setContentText("Could not load data from file:\n"
                    + file.getPath());

            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here Is the Error code

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: A bound value cannot be set.
    at javafx.beans.property.DoublePropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at sb.basket.model.Items.setTotal(Items.java:83)
    at sb.basket.model.Items$JaxbAccessorM_getTotal_setTotal_double.set(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor.receive(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at sb.basket.MainApp.loadItemDataFromFile(MainApp.java:201)
    at sb.basket.view.RootLayoutController.handleOpen(RootLayoutController.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The error means exactly what it says: a bound value cannot be set. So presumably somewhere you are trying to call `setTotal(...)` on an `Items` instance (either explicitly or implicitly). Consider using a `ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper` for `total` and only exposing `getTotal()` and `public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty totalProperty()` methods.

Comment: If i put my code on github could you take a look ? :) @James_D

Comment: No. External links to code may break in the future, which would make your question useless to other users. Create (from scratch if necessary) a [MCVE] (please read the link to see exactly what that means) and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would think that the XML representation is storing the total, and when you unmarshal, it is trying to set it. Since total is a derived property, you should not be persisting it in the first place. (I don't know JAXB well enough to know the details of how to do that.)

Comment: I have added the BasketOverViewController and do you think this is where the error stands,      totalColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue()
                .totalProperty().asObject());

Comment: NumberBinding multiplication = Bindings.multiply(
  this.priceDoubleProperty(), this.quantityIntegerProperty());
  this.totalProperty().bind(multiplication); 

I removed this from my code and it works however now my total column doesn't calculate which is expected :/// hmm I wonder what I can to fix this

Comment: Well obviously you will not get the error if the value is not bound. You need to [edit] your question according to the advice in the [help] center. Specifically: write a [MCVE] that shows the problem - right now the code you posted is incomplete and cluttered up with irrelevant stuff that has nothing to do with the issue.  Include the complete stack trace and use it to identify which line in your code is generating the error. Right now you haven't even said where the error is coming from.

Comment: The stack trace makes it pretty clear why the error is happening, no?

Comment: Yes it does, but I don't how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JavaFX binding indicates that the value of a property should always be equal to some expression. Specifically, in your code

```
NumberBinding multiplication = Bindings.multiply(
    this.priceDoubleProperty(), this.quantityIntegerProperty());
this.totalProperty().bind(multiplication);
```

you declare that `total` should always be `price x quantity`.

It is illegal to set a bound value (because setting it to a value would break the binding, i.e. violate the contract implied by making it bound).

Effectively, you have made `total` a "derived property`: its value is completely determined by other values (in the same object, in this case). Consequently:

1. You should not persist the `total`, since it is redundant to do so.
2. You should not expose any API that makes it possible to set the total.

Your exception occurs because when you unmarshal the XML via JAXB, the deserialization process attempts to set the total (which is stored in the XML file). I am not too familiar with JAXB, but the following should work (note that this will not be compatible with any previous XML file storing the items; also I have fixed some method names so they match the JavaFX Properties Pattern):

```
public class Items {

    private final StringProperty name;
    private final IntegerProperty quantity;
    private final DoubleProperty price;
    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper total;

      public Items() {
          this(null,0,0); 
          }


    public Items(String name, int quantity, double price) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.quantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty(quantity);
        this.price = new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);
        this.total = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper();
        NumberBinding multiplication = Bindings.multiply(
        this.priceDoubleProperty(), this.quantityProperty());
        this.total.bind(multiplication);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity.get();
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity.set(quantity);
    }

    public IntegerProperty quantityProperty() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price.get();
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    public DoubleProperty priceProperty() {
        return price;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public double getTotal() {
        return total.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty totalProperty() {
        return total.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

}
```